# What to do when two answers are awesome

Tags: feature-request, reputation, etiquette

Sometimes, one questions gets two really good answers. Provided that both answers are equally good,  I know I have to eventually pick one, and I guess it would be an arbitrary choice. However, is there any way to *split* the points or give the other person some points in any way?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have three independent options:

1. Approving an answer.
2. Upvoting an answer.
3. Commenting.

You have to make a choice concerning #1, but ##2 and 3 are available for all answers.  Use them liberally to indicate your satisfaction.  In some cases you might choose to let timeliness be the tie breaker: approve the earlier answer.

Comment: I up-voted both answers and left comments as well as picked one as the most accurate considering what I has asked (not how useful one of the answers was). I wish there was a split decision option... new feature?

Comment: @Ragi See the closely related discussion at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2786/accept-multiple-answers-or-split-bounty-among-several-users .